# Extract information from Ldap Value string

Tags: c#, .net, ldap

I'm getting all users from all groups in LDAP using the follwoing code

```
        using (SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll())
        {
            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
                 ResultPropertyValueCollection userValueCollection =
                   result.Properties["member"];
                    foreach (var cn in userValueCollection)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine(cn.ToString());
                    }

            }
        }
```

The out put is the following:

CN=068IGHf,OU=Personal,OU=Generic,OU=Privileged CN=064IMHf,OU=Technical,OU=Generic,OU=Privileged CN=060IGHJ,OU=Functional,OU=Generic,OU=Privileged CN=061UGHf,OU=Tester,OU=Generic,OU=Privileged

Q1: How can i get the type information of each user example: Personal, Technical, Functional
from the output?
Q2: How can i only get the userName only example: 068IGHF?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `User.ToString()` and then expect to be able to parse the resulting string.

The `User` object has methods and attributes of its own. Use them.

For example to get the common name:

```
 DirectoryEntry user = new DirectoryEntry(result.Properties["member"]);

 group.Users.Add(user.Properties.Item["cn"][0]);
```

Comment: How did you arrive to this method 'Properties.Item' I cannot find it?

Comment: i'm using .net 3.5 and i still cannot find Properties.Item as memeber of DirectoryEntry???

Comment: @user2019737, well, it's there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.properties.aspx, and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.propertycollection.item.aspx